# Does radiation level of an antenna depend on the antenna's parameters?

Tags: antenna, low-power, telecommunications

I am a newbie when it comes to the theory of telecommunication. I wonder whether radiation exposure may exceed recommended safety levels after changing the antenna only? I'm asking since I've seen people making their own antennas for various mobile devices, such as phone built-in bluetooth or wifi modules. An example can be found here:

https://dl.xda-developers.com/3/4/3/1/3/0/4/DSC06952.jpg?key=nOTc6qou05QQmaIKa6IgEg&ts=1508944630

I think it is possible in theory as a material that an antenna is made of as well as its dimensions may influence radiation resistance. Also, shape of an antenna influences gain, which may result in sending more energy in one direction. Is it something that should be considered in practice though when it comes to low power devices such as phone wifi, GSM or bluetooth modules, wifi routers that one uses at home etc.?

Comment: An antenna can never radiate more energy than the device puts into it.

Comment: I understand it, but I can imagine that the ratio of energy dissipated e.g. as heat to the one that is radiated may vary depending on the antenna design.

Comment: I don't know enough to provide an answer to a safety critical question, but as a comment, I'll point out that yes, a narrow beam can concentrate the energy into a smaller region.  It's literally the difference between a steel-cutting laser and a flashlight.  However, I do not know enough to know whether you, as a mere mortal, can craft an antenna with a narrow enough pattern to actually cause issues with the 500mA limit on unlicensed devices (like wifi routers).